# Sort Array in IBM EGL

Tags: egl

I have in (ibm) EGL an arry of following record:

```
record FreelanceOrderRec
    orderNr                     int;
    date                        date;
    installerNr                 int;
    partOfDay                   string;
    ....
end
```

orderNr is the key of the order,

installeNr also (personel files),

date is the date our freelancer will install the order

PartOfday is during what hours the installer will go to the client,
it can have following  values:

```
"1 (08:00-13:00)";          
"2 (11:00-15:00)";
"3 (13:00-17:00)";
"Not Known.";
```

This array is scrambled and I want to order it like this:

date desc, installeNr desc, PartOfday desc

how can I order an array like that in egl?

```
(freelanceOrderRecs FreelanceOrderRec[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library to sort any array using a delegate that compares items:

```
package tc;

delegate SortComparer(a any in, b any in) returns(int)
    // compares 2 items for sorting
    // returns 0 if the items are equal
    // returns < 0 if a < b
    // returns > 0 if a > b
end

library ArrayUtils
    function sort(array any[] in, compare SortComparer in) returns(any[])
        quickSort(array, compare, 1, array.getSize());
        return(array);
    end

    private function quickSort(array any[] in, compare SortComparer in, left int in, right int in)
        index int = partition(array, compare, left, right);
        if(left < index - 1)
            quickSort(array, compare, left, index - 1);
        end
        if(right > index)
            quickSort(array, compare, index, right);
        end
    end

    private function partition(array any[] in, compare SortComparer in, left int in, right int in) returns(int)
        pivot any = array[(left + right) / 2];
        while(left <= right)
            while(compare(array[left], pivot) < 0)
                left += 1;
            end
            while(compare(array[right], pivot) > 0)
                right -= 1;
            end
            if(left <= right)
                swap any = array[left];
                array[left] = array[right];
                array[right] = swap;
                left += 1;
                right -= 1;
            end
        end
        return(left);
    end
end
```

And here's the code to use it with your record type:

```
freelanceOrderRecs = ArrayUtils.sort(freelanceOrderRecs as any[], compareFreelanceOrderRecs) as FreelanceOrderRec[];

private function compareFreelanceOrderRecs(a any in, b any in) returns(int)
    recA FreelanceOrderRec = a;
    recB FreelanceOrderRec = b;
    case
    when(recA.date < recB.date) return(1);
    when(recA.date > recB.date) return(-1);
    when(recA.installerNr < recB.installerNr) return(1);
    when(recA.installerNr > recB.installerNr) return(-1);
    when(recA.partOfDay < recB.partOfDay) return(1);
    when(recA.partOfDay > recB.partOfDay) return(-1);
    otherwise return(0);
    end
end
```